# C++ Multiplying Large Matrices

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen

I am working on Physics research as an undergraduate and for it I have to multiply large matrices on the order of 348x348 using c++.  My teacher had me test my code using smaller matrices such as a 6x6 and 12x12 and with those matrices, I got exactly what I was looking for.  But, when I try and use the same exact code for the 348x348 case, I am not getting the correct output for the multiplication of the matrices.  I have the program reading in some data and putting the data as a matrix, and I have checked to make sure that all the data has been read in correctly.  But, I am still just not getting the correct product of the matrices.  I am using the c++ library Eigen, and I am reading in the numbers for the elements of the matrix as doubles.  My teacher has done the calculation with her own program and she is getting the correct result.  So, I was just wondering if someone could point me in the right direction in figuring out what is wrong?

```
myOutfile << NormCoord.transpose() * SqrtMass * NormCoord << endl;
```

This is the actual multiplication. I should be getting the identity matrix, but with the larger matrix the diagonal elements are off by a factor of 2 and some of the off-diagonal elements are a little too large on the order of 0.0001 when I want them to be at least on the order of 10^(-6)

Comment: We probably can, but only if you post at least some of your code.  Without seeing what you've done, it's anybody's guess as to what you've done wrong.

Comment: Posting the code would help, without the code it is impossible to know what the problem is.

Comment: Which part of my code should I post? It is a pretty simple code simply because Eigen makes working with matrices so easy and like I said, when using smaller matrices I was getting the correct output.

Comment: Post the part where you think it is the relevant

Comment: const int NUMBER_OF_COORDINATES = 348;

Comment: Specifically, the part where the product is actually being calculated.  You can probably leave out the part where you take input and the part where you print output.  And don't post the code in comments... edit it into the original question.

Comment: Okay, I edited it into the original post.

Comment: Hi, a bit off topic posssibly, however another thing to keep in mind is the lack of precision in CPU mathematics as well, I would allow an appropriate epsilon and use that as your tolerance level.  I have had wildly varying answers whilst calculating simple values such as PI when dealing with different CPU families (Intel, AMD and ARM).  ALso if you post the actual calculation code behind the code-line above we can probably help out a bit more:)

Answer (score 0):

My guess: the problem is where you *save* your matrix data to the file.

See, if you save `double` to a file like this:

```
double d=...;
out_file<<d;
```

and then later read it from the file like this:

```
in_file>>d;
```

**you don't get the same number**. The double is truncated on writing and you get only the approximate number (with a significant error I might add)

You won't be able to see the error when you print the matrix, as the numbers are truncated exactly where you don't print them. But when you multiply the data as a matrix of 348x348 - the error multiplies by a factor of 348*2=696 making it big enough to see.

Same thing with `printf/scanf`.

The solution? when you write the data add precision:

```
out_file<<std::setprecision(20)<<d; // need to #include<iomanip>
```

(I put 20 for no good reason other than "it's a lot". Maybe you need more or less - I'm not sure what the precision of doubles really is)

Or better yet - save is binary data if you can.

**edit**: in `printf` you do this:

```
printf("%.20lf",d);
```

Comment: You forgot to write, that he can also encode binary data into text (e.g. `base64` encoding) and write that.